# After the upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS in gwenview plugins missing

Tags: 16.04

After the upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS in gwenview plugins missing. When I click on plugins there is only "KXML Hello world image"

I used to work with that plugins especially with the Meta data - because I check the pictures that upload in my site with the news for rights.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [Gentoo Forum thread](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1048658.html)

#### Problem

> So, I just installed kipi-plugins-5.0.0, so I could finally update gwenview to a KF5 version, but it seems that all plugins except import/export have just disappeared. Am I doing something wrong, or is it just one more case of the developers telling us "you think you want it, but you don't"?

#### Reason

> Anyway, `kipi-plugins` is not maintained by 'the KDE guys' but by 'the `digikam` guy' and he **decided to move these plugins into digikam** in the process of porting to KF5/Qt5 and become platform independent (read: MacOS, Windows).

#### Solution

There is not really one except using another tool to do the job.

Comment: Yes, I love Gwenview, but now I use gThumb. It is no the same, but similar.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that kipi-plugins are not compiled to Qt5 yet. Hopefully it will soon be. As a workaround one can either use digikam's batch processing or imagemagick (for example 'convert-resize').

Answer (score -1):

I switched to Nomacs http://nomacs.org/ that is also a Qt5-based program for batch processing like renaming, resizing, flipping, etc. It's in the repos, it has a PPA.